# Docker for windows にて it looks like there is an error with Docker Desktop, Restart to fix it と表示される。

Tags: docker, windows-server

Docker for windows にて `it looks like there is an error with Docker Desktop, Restart to fix it` と表示され、困っています。
Dockerの再起動や再インストール、設定などもいじってはみたのですが効果がありません。
また挙動もおかしく、起動すると一定時間`Docker desktop waiting...`と表示されたのち勝手に落ちてしまいます。
ちなみにその一時的起動している時に変更した設定は全て反映されません。
あまり詳しいわけではないので不足情報等あるかと思われますが、何卒お力をお貸しください
よろしくお願いします。

OSは Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter です

Comment: [システム要件](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#system-requirements)としてはWindows10/11、 また[nested virtualization](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/general/#can-i-run-docker-desktop-in-nested-virtualization-scenarios), [virtualized hardware](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/general/#can-i-run-docker-desktop-on-virtualized-hardware)は未サポートのようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決
システムアップデートを行い、docker desktopやWSL2などを全て入れ直した結果、解決とは行きませんが別のエラーに変わりました。
一歩前進・・・ということですかね
コメントありがとうございました。